# Save a file under another name exactly as it was on a specific date/commit without changing branch or reverting

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I am a git newbie, I am using git to track simple txt files (R scripts). I don't have branches or all the features git supports, I am just using git to track the changes I do to a couple of text scripts in each project (and thus avoid renaming a file every time I do a change to track changes).

I am in a situation where I would like to open a file exactly how it was on a specific date/commit and save it under another name without changing branch or workspace (stay on master) or reverting/modifying any other files (including this specific file as it is now).

How can I do this?

**Update** : Is there a way to do this using a GUI (preferably in linux)?

Comment: `git show @{yesterday}:path/to/file >extract.r`. See [`git revisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for the @ syntax.

Comment: @jthill: make this as answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git show @{yesterday}:path/to/file >extract.r`. See [git revisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for the @ syntax

Comment: Many thanks. What would be the format of @{yesterday}. Could you please provide an example. I am on linux, if it makes a difference

Comment: The linked docs are for that format, and every other way of specifying commits.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this using a GUI so as to better examine the code? I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

command:

```
git show {commithash}:{path} > {newfilename}
```

example:

```
git show 50559d3:conf/routes > routes-back-then.txt
```